what is a "string" in bash?
i keep hearing people talking about "strings"?
what is a string? what are people talking about?
i keep hearing "enter a string" or "if your string this" or your "string that"?
what does it mean to enter a string in bash?
any help would be appreciated, i'm genuinely confused at what it's supposed to mean
when i ask google it tells me "Bash String is a data type similar to integer or boolean. " and i have no idea what this is supposed to mean
thank you

You do realize context is rather important, esp. when asking about rather generic things? In general, a string is a sequence of characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science). That is, text. But that has nothing to with Bash in particular, and we can't know if you're thinking about something more specific.

String is a sequence of characters.
See String (computer science) in Wikipedia for more details.

what separates two strings? spaces? a comma? quotes?
